# Is every open set in a base space evenly covered?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $C$ be a covering space of $B$.

Then, does every open set in $B$ evenly covered by a covering map?

This must be false but I cannot find a counterexample.. Please help

Comment: What examples of coverings do you know?

Comment: $e^{2\pi t}$, $e^z$ and etc..

Comment: Of course by the definition of a covering space, each **point** of $B$ is in a set evenly covered by a covering map, which is a "local" property.  Therefore if you want a counter-example, I suggest that you choose a very simple (but non-trivial) example of a covering space, and a very **big** open set in $B$ (ie to avoid the "local" property).

Comment: It's not clear to me how those are different covering spaces. If one of those is supposed to be an $n$-fold covering of the circle by itself, I'd suggest you think about that.

Comment: What's the largest possible open set you can think of in the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every open subset of $B$  is evenly covered if and only if the covering $C\to B$ is trivial. Duh!

Comment: What do you mean a covering is trivial?

Comment: The covering $C\to B$ is trivial if it is a product $C=B \times D$ with $D$ a discrete space. Equivalently, $C$ is a disjoint sum of copies of $B$.

Comment: You also need that the covering is a homeomorphism when restricted to an individual connected component in $C$. Take for example the cover of the circle by two circles, each of which is mapped individually onto a base circle by the doubling map. This is not trivial.

Comment: @Daniel: I disagree with  your objection. Your covering is **not** the product $B\times D$ of the base with a discrete space. In my second description it is obvious that I mean that the disjoint union is mapped to the base by a mapping that restricts to the identity on each summand, and not to some artificially constructed  map. By the way, considerations of connected components are irrelevant in my definition, which is general and valid for a completely disconnected base for example.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have said connected component, (I was assuming connected base space). The space in my example is a product of $S^1$ and $\{0,1\}$, but I agree, the covering is not a projection map onto the base space factor of the product, which would be necessary for triviality. I just think it's important to make this explicit for the OP, as your comment made it seem like the total space was all that mattered, and not necessarily the covering map.

Comment: @Daniel: I think we agree .